# Precedence of stdin and stdout redirection in Bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection

My question is about redirection precedence is bash. Suppose you have a command:

`cmd1 < cmd2 > cmd3`

Would it translate to:

`(cmd1 < cmd2) > cmd3`

Or

`cmd1 < (cmd2 > cmd3)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [POSIX standard specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html) that shell redirection is from left to right; that is, order is significant:

> The construct `2>&1` is often used to redirect standard error to the same file as standard output. Since the redirections take place beginning to end, the order of redirections is significant. For example:
>
> ```
> ls > foo 2>&1
> ```
>
> directs both standard output and standard error to file `foo`. However:
>
> ```
> ls 2>&1 > foo
> ```
>
> only directs standard output to file `foo` because standard error was duplicated as standard output before standard output was directed to file `foo`.

`bash` operates in compliance with this part of the standard:

```
$ ls doesnotexist > foo 2>&1
$ cat foo
ls: cannot access doesnotexist: No such file or directory
$ ls doesnotexist 2>&1 > foo
ls: cannot access doesnotexist: No such file or directory
$ cat foo
$
```

As for piping:

> Because pipeline assignment of standard input or standard output or both takes place before redirection, it can be modified by redirection. For example:
>
> ```
> $ command1 2>&1 | command2
> ```
>
> sends both the standard output and standard error of `command1` to the standard input of `command2`.

Comment: That assumes that the Bash shell is POSIX-complient.

Comment: I am not getting it. Since you said order is from left to right, shouldn't `ls > foo 2>&1` mean redirect stdout to foo then redirect stderr to stdout. So this shouldn't work. Similarly second command should work. What am I missing here?

Comment: @fpmurphy `bash` is generally POSIX compliant, except in the situations [outlined here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html), where the default `bash` behavior differs. To make `bash` conform more, you can use the `--posix` option.

Comment: @dpacmittal The first example, `ls > foo 2>&1`, operates like this: first, standard output is redirected to `foo`, then, standard error is redirected to standard output, which is now the file `foo`. The second example, `ls 2>&1 > foo`, operates like this: standard error is redirected to standard output before standard output is redirected to `foo`, so standard error is echoed locally instead of being directed to the file.

Comment: @fred: Thanks for your answer. I tried all the examples and they work as documented. But I don't get the logic behind it. If the order is from left to right `ls 2>&1 >foo` would mean:

1. Redirect any output from stderr to stdin
2. Redirect any output from stdin to foo.
3. Execute ls.

So theoretically stderr->stdin->foo is the order we are mentioning in the command which seems perfectly legitimate to me. I understand it doesn't work, but I am not getting what's wrong with it.

Comment: @dpacmittal... Yes, I agree that it can look counter-intuitive until you "get" it, and I found that it helped using 'wc' in tests to identify which stream was going where... and really all these are output examples and your quetion cites an input example as well ... I believe the input can go either side of the command (but I don't enough about it to say that that is always the case.

Comment: @dpacmittal..  re `ls 2>&1 >foo`  maybe you can think of it like this. stderr from 'ls' is redirected to stdout. This **will happen!** It will go to where stdout is **currently** assigned to go, regardless of any further directives relating to stdout.. (because this is its *prime/first directive*)..  Then along come another  directive which says that stdout will go to "foo", and it does... Remember: stderr is not transmuted into actually becoming stdout.. It just goes to where stdout **was** assigned at the time of the directive. (eg, the terminal)

Comment: @fred: That's the only way it makes sense. I was thinking it in terms of pipes (fluid pipes) wherein stderr got connected to stdout and stdout to foo and the output was fed from one end. Not it makes sense. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @dpacmittal: and thanks to you too for asking the pressing questions, because I came to realize that didn't fully understand it myself until I needed to explain it clearly... Questons have a way of putting a new light on things :)

Answer (score 4):

I guess neither.  A pair of parenthesis means a sub-shell.  But in this case, no sub-shell will be started because of the redirection.  Bash simply feeds `cmd2` into stdin and feeds stdout into `cmd3`.

I'm thinking, do you mean something like `cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3`?  Because your `cmd2` and `cmd3` are usually normal files instead of "cmds".